# How to create a query with phpMoAdmin?

Tags: mongodb, database

I just installed phpMoAdmin to manipulate my MongoDb collection but i can't find any tuto that show me how to use it

Any idea 
ThankYou

Comment: While this not answer question, but have you tried rockmongo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use PHP array syntax.  Let's say you're looking for a field "name" and a value of "Smith".  You need to type this into the "Query" box in phpMoAdmin:

```
array('name' => 'Smith')
```

You would then click on the "Query" button.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to choose a database. After that, click 'Change database' button. 
You will see all the collections. Or just add one. As soon as you select any of collections, you'll be able to see the list of possible actions. The last one in this list is 'query'.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to search by `id`. The decision is:

1. hit link `search` (not `query`)
2. choose field `_id`
3. type (mongoid)`your_id` e.g. (mongoid)584179ee073be8d803865b0a
4. hit button `search`